# Can you use sandbags as your discard when you have more than 5 cards?

Tags: forbidden-island

I have 4 cards, take my turn, then draw two cards with one of them being sandbags. I must now discard a card to be at 5. Can I *use* the sandbag card instead of discarding even though I have 6 cards in hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**  Page 6 of the [rules](http://www.gamewright.com/gamewright/pdfs/Rules/ForbiddenIslandTM-RULES.pdf) states

> Note: You may use the power of a Special Action card if you are 
>   forced to discard it.